# Kernel object won't unload

Tags: kernel, freebsd

Loading a kernel module is not an issue.

```
kldload ./stepper.ko
```

However, when I try to unload it I get this:

```
kldunload -f stepper.ko
kldunload: can't unload file: Operation not supported
```

Doesn't work the -i or -n options, either. I'm running FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p9 in VMware Workstation. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Does your modevent function handle MOD_UNLOAD?

Comment: Yes. Here is a snippet:

    `case MOD_LOAD:
       uprintf("Loading successful\n");
       break;

    case MOD_UNLOAD:
       uprintf("Unloading successful\n");
       break;`

Unloading the KO prints the message; however, it then gives the aforementioned error message. kldstat shows that the .ko is still loaded.

Comment: Okay, but what's the value returned by that routine?

Answer (score 0):

My VM crashed and I installed a new one. The kernel module no loads just fine. Both VMs were identical so not sure why the first would not load.